# For coprime $a,b$, why is $\operatorname{gcd} (a,2b)$ equal to $1$ if $a$ is odd, or $2$ if $a$ is even?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, education

Let $a, b$ be integers (with at least one of $a, b$ non-zero) with $\operatorname{gcd}(a,b) = d$

If $d = 1$, then $\operatorname{gcd}(a, 2b) = 1$ if $a$ is odd, or $2$ if a is even

Can somebody prove why this is?

Answer (score 3):

Consider $d_1=\gcd(a,2b)$

$d_1|2a$ and $d_1|2b$ so

$d_1|\gcd(2a,2b)=2\gcd(a,b)=2d=2$

So either $d_1=1$ or $d_1=2$.

If $a$ is odd then we can only have $d_1=1$

If $a$ is even then we can only have $d_1=2$

Comment: Why these downvotes? Bill Dubuque's solution too is very short and nice, why it is downvoted?

Comment: In $d_1|\gcd(2a,2b)=2\gcd(a,b)=2d=2$, why is $d := \gcd(a, b)$ assumed to equal $1$?

Comment: @joseville if $2d=2$, what else can $d$ be?

Comment: I agree that if $2d = 2$, then $d$ must equal $1$. What I don't understand is where we got that $2d$ equals $2$.

Comment: Which step you don't understand? $\gcd(2a,2b)=2\gcd(a,b)$?

Comment: Oh sorry. I do understand that part. I didn't understand where $gcd(a, b) = d = 1$ came from, but I reread the question and $d = 1$ is a given. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ is even, then $b$ must be odd since otherwise $\gcd(a,b)=2\not=1$.  Then, since $2$ and $b$ are relatively prime,
$$
\gcd(a,2b)=\gcd(a,2)\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,2).
$$
Since $a$ is even, $2$ divides $a$, so $\gcd(a,2)=2$.

On the other hand, if $a$ is odd, then we can write $b=2^kc$ where $c$ is odd.  By the same argument above,
$$
\gcd(a,2b)=\gcd(a,2^{k+1}c)=\gcd(a,2^{k+1})\gcd(a,c).
$$ 
Since $a$ is odd, it does not have a factor of $2$.  Therefore, both gcd's are $1$.

Answer (score 1):

By Euclid: $\,\gcd(a,b)=1\,\Rightarrow\,(a,bc) = (a,c).\ $ Yours is special case $\,c = 2$

Comment: Surely this question is a duplicate.  Please take care to not answer duplicate questions already  abundantly available on math.se.provided.  Rather, familiarize yourself with the many duplicates, and instead of answering, close such a question as a duplicate of any one of many, many posts with answers addressing this same question.

Answer (score 0):

if $a$ is even, then $a$ is divisible by $2$. Because we're multiplying $b$ by $2$, it will always be divisible by $2$.

In  other words, if $a$ is even, you can always divide $a, 2b$ by $2$, but if it's odd, it will only be divisible by $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a prime $p$ divides $a$ and $2b$, since it divides $2b$ it must either divide $2$ or $b$, so if $p\neq 2$ then $p|b$. This is a contradiction since no prime should divide both $a$ and $b$.

Clearly if $a$ is even then $2$ divides both $a$ and $2b$, so we must only prove that $4$ cannot divide both $a$ and $2b$, notice that indeed this cannot be the case, as we would have that both $a$ and $b$ are even.